# How to evaluate a classifier with PySpark 2.4.5

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, evaluation

I'm wondering what the best way is to evaluate a fitted binary classification model using Apache Spark 2.4.5 and PySpark (Python). I want to consider different metrics such as accuracy, precision, recall, auc and f1 score.

Let us assume that the following is given:

```
# pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame in VectorAssembler format containing two columns: target and features
# DataFrame we want to evaluate
df

# Fitted pyspark.ml.tuning.TrainValidationSplitModel (any arbitrary ml algorithm)
model
```

**1. Option**

Neither [BinaryClassificationEvaluator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.BinaryClassificationEvaluator) nor [MulticlassClassificationEvaluator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.MulticlassClassificationEvaluator) can calculate all metrics mentioned above on their own. Thus, we use both evaluators.

```
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import BinaryClassificationEvaluator, MulticlassClassificationEvaluator

# Create both evaluators
evaluatorMulti = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(labelCol="target", predictionCol="prediction")
evaluator = BinaryClassificationEvaluator(labelCol="target", rawPredictionCol="prediction", metricName='areaUnderROC')

# Make predicitons
predictionAndTarget = model.transform(df).select("target", "prediction")

# Get metrics
acc = evaluatorMulti.evaluate(predictionAndTarget, {evaluatorMulti.metricName: "accuracy"})
f1 = evaluatorMulti.evaluate(predictionAndTarget, {evaluatorMulti.metricName: "f1"})
weightedPrecision = evaluatorMulti.evaluate(predictionAndTarget, {evaluatorMulti.metricName: "weightedPrecision"})
weightedRecall = evaluatorMulti.evaluate(predictionAndTarget, {evaluatorMulti.metricName: "weightedRecall"})
auc = evaluator.evaluate(predictionAndTarget)
```

*Downside*

- It seems weird and contradictory to use MulticlassClassificationEvaluator when evaluating a binary classifier
- I have to use two different evaluators to calculate five metrics
- MulticlassClassificationEvaluator only calculates `weightedPrecision` and `weightedRecall` (which is ok for a multi class classification). However, are these two metrics equal to `precision` and `recall` in a binary case ?

**2. Option**

Using RDD based API with [BinaryClassificatinMetrics](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics) and [MulticlassMetrics](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics). Again, both metrics can't calculate all metrics mentioned above on their own (at least not in python ..). Thus, we use both.

```
from pyspark.mllib.evaluation import BinaryClassificationMetrics, MulticlassMetrics

# Make prediction
predictionAndTarget = model.transform(df).select("target", "prediction")

# Create both evaluators
metrics_binary = BinaryClassificationMetrics(predictionAndTarget.rdd.map(tuple))
metrics_multi = MulticlassMetrics(predictionAndTarget.rdd.map(tuple))

acc = metrics_multi.accuracy
f1 = metrics_multi.fMeasure(1.0)
precision = metrics_multi.precision(1.0)
recall = metrics_multi.recall(1.0)
auc = metrics_binary.areaUnderROC
```

*Downsides*

- According to Spark, RDD-based API is now in maintenance mode and [DataFrame-based API is primary API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/ml-guide.html)
- Again, I have to use two different metrics to calculate five metrics
- Again, using MulticlassMetrics seems contradictory when evaluating a binary classifier

*Upside*

- In my case (~1.000.000 rows) Option 2 seems to be faster than Option 1

*Surprise*

- In my case I get different `f1` and `areaUnderRoc` values when using Option 1 vs when using Option 2.

**Option 3**

Use numpy and sklearn

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, roc_auc_score, f1_score

# Make predicitons
predictionAndTarget = model.transform(df).select("target", "prediction")

predictionAndTargetNumpy = np.array((predictionAndTarget.collect()))

acc = accuracy_score(predictionAndTargetNumpy[:,0], predictionAndTargetNumpy[:,1])
f1 = f1_score(predictionAndTargetNumpy[:,0], predictionAndTargetNumpy[:,1])
precision = precision_score(predictionAndTargetNumpy[:,0], predictionAndTargetNumpy[:,1])
recall = recall_score(predictionAndTargetNumpy[:,0], predictionAndTargetNumpy[:,1])
auc = roc_auc_score(predictionAndTargetNumpy[:,0], predictionAndTargetNumpy[:,1])
```

*Downside*

- Using sklearn and numpy seems to be weird as Apache Spark is claiming to have there own API for Evaluation
- Using numpy and sklearn can even be impossible if the dataset is getting too big.

To summarize my questions:

1. Which Option above (if any) is recommended for evaluating a binary classifier using Apache Spark 2.4.5 and PySpark.
2. Are there other Options? Am I missing something important?
3. Why do I get different results for the metrics when using Option 1 vs when using Option 2

Comment: I tried your first method and it works only for accuracy.

Comment: Having tried to use Spark's `MulticlassClassificationEvaluator`, I can only second OP's comments above. It is confusing that not all metrics are provided by one evaluator class. It would be great to have something like sklearn's classification_report in Spark, too.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it is relevant now , but can answer your question 3 and thus may be question 1 inturn-

Spark ML provides Weighted Precision & Weighted Recall metrics only as part of MulticlassClassificationEvaluator module.
If you're looking to have equivalent interpretation of Overall Precision metric, especially incase of Binary Classification equivalent to Scikit world , then better to compute Confusion Matrix and evaluate using the formula of Precision & Recall

Weighted precision ,used by Spark ML ,is computed using precision of both the classes and then adding using weight of each class label in test set i.e.

```
Prec (Label 1) = TP/(TP+FP)
Prec (Label 0) = TN/(TN+FN)
Weight of Label 1 in test set WL1 = L1/(L1+L2)
Weight of Label 0 in test set WL2 = L2/(L1+L2)
Weighted precision = (PrecL1 * WL1) + (PrecL0 * WL2)
```

Weighted Precision &Recall will be more than Overall Precision & Recall in case of even slight class imbalance in the dataset and thus metrics between Sklearn based & Spark ML based will differ.

As an illustration , a Confusion Matrix of class imbalance dataset as below :

```
 array([[3969025,  445123],
       [ 284283, 1663913]])
 
 Total 1 Class labels   1948196
 Total 0 Class labels   4414148

 Proportion Label 1 :0.306207272
 Proportion Label 0 :0.693792728


Spark ML will give metrics :
Accuracy : 0.8853557745384405
Weighted Precision : 0.8890015815237463
WeightedRecall :    0.8853557745384406
F-1 Score  :  0.8865644697253956
```

whereas Actual Overall metrics computation gives (Scikit Equivalent):

```
 Accuracy:  0.8853557745384405
 Precision: 0.7889448070113549
 Recall:    0.8540788503826103
 AUC:   0.8540788503826103
 f1:    0.8540788503826103
```

Thus Spark ML weighted version inflates the otherwise Overall metric computation that we observe especially for Binary Classification

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! However, my question was why I got different results when using Option 1 (Spark ML DataFrame based API)  vs when using Option 2 (Spark ML RDD based API). And I'm not sure how your explanation is answering my first question (Which option is recommended)?

Comment: Shouldn't it be "Total 1 Class labels" 3969025 + 445123=4414148 ?

Comment: I'm sorry but if the weight for class 1 is basically L1=(TP+FP)/(TP+FP+FN+TN) and I have to multiply by TP/(TP+FP) and then for class 0 L0=(TN+FN)/(TP+FP+FN+TN)  and TN/(TN+FN) , if I add together I basically get the accuracy (TP + TN)/(TP + TN + FP + FN)

Comment: Good approach for pure evaluation, but hot to use it as evaluator for CrossValidator object? I mean, how to run CrossValidator based on f1(scikit learn equivalent)